# showing the legend for javafx candle sample

Tags: javafx, legend

Do you know how to show the legend in an advanced JavaFX XYChart (starting with the candle example from Ensemble I'm trying to add the legend).

Best Regards,
Oren

Comment: post some code or give a link the we ll help

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html specificly the custom chart (candle)  http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Charts/Custom/Adv Candle Stick Chart

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it.

Extending `LineChart` does the trick (instead of the abstract `XYChart`).

Also make sure you give names to the series, and have something like:

```
series0.chart-line-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
}
```

In your style/css definitions.